# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar en una lista los valores generados aleatoriamente del siguiente código?

Tags: python, bucle-for, math

Estoy haciendo un programa que genera sucesiones aritméticas de forma aleatoria. El programa funciona correctamente, pero el problema surge al momento de almacenar estas sucesiones en una lista porque al momento de imprimir la lista me aparece una sola sucesión y no "x" cantidad de sucesiones que yo había generado.

```
from random import choice, randint

alm=[]
s=int(input('¿Cuántas sucesiones quieres hacer? '))
r=int(input('¿Qué longitud quieres que tenga cada sucesión? '))
ra=int(input('Elige el rango: del 1 al... : '))


for j in range(s):
    g,d,x=randint(1,ra), randint(1,15), randint(1,150)
    print(f'\n\n{j+1}.- ¿Cuál será el valor de término número {x} de la siguiente sucesión:')
    alm.append(j)
    for i in range(1, r+1):
    
        a=d+i*g
        print(f'    {a}', end="")
        alm.append(a) //En esta lista almaceno los valores aleatoriamente

print('\n---------------------------------------------\n\n')

for m in range(s):
    for n in range(j):
        print(f'{alm[m]}', end=" ") //Aquí imprimo los valores que se almacenaron en la lista, pero solo me imprime una sola sucesión.
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema? Les agradezco mucho su tiempo y paciencia, saludos.

Comment: En Python para hacer un comentario de una línea se usa `#`

Comment: Para imprimir una línea horizontal, queda mejor con este caracter: `—`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya los estoy utilizando. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint

res = []
sucesiones = int(input('¿Cuántas sucesiones quieres hacer? '))
longitud = int(input('¿Qué longitud quieres que tenga cada sucesión? '))
rango = int(input('Elige el rango: del 1 al... : '))

for i in range(sucesiones):
    g, d, x = randint(1,rango), randint(1,15), randint(1,150)
    print("\n\n", str(i+1), "¿Cuál será el valor de término número", str(x), "de la siguiente sucesión:")
    for j in range(1, longitud+1):
        a = d + j * g
        if j in (longitud, longitud-1):
            res.append(a)
        print(a, sep="\t")

print('\n———————————————————————————————————————————————————\n\n')

for i in range(0, len(res), 2):
    diferencia = res[i+1] - res[i]
    termino = res[i+1] + diferencia
    print(termino)
```

Almacenas en `res` los dos últimos valores que se muestran (para cada sucesión). Calculas el valor siguiente como la suma del último valor mostrado más la diferencia entre los dos últimos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Tu código me ayudó mucho a optimizar la forma de almacenar las listas. Solo un detalle, al momento de calcular la sucesión arroja la respuesta incorrecta, pero ya corregí esa parte, abajo comenté mi pregunta con el código modificado y optimizado. Te voto como solución para que puedas ayudar a más personas. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

archivo=open('Sucesiones_con_respuesta.txt', 'w')
alm=[]
s=int(input('¿Cuántas sucesiones quieres hacer? '))
r=int(input('¿Qué longitud quieres que tenga cada sucesión? ')) #No pongas más de 4 números o generará un error en el resultado, estoy trabajando para arreglar eso
ra=int(input('Elige el rango: del 1 al... : '))


for j in range(s):
    g,d,x=randint(1,ra), randint(1,15), randint(1,150)
    print(f'\n\n{j+1}.- ¿Cuál será el valor de término número {x} de la siguiente sucesión:')
    archivo.write(f'\n\n{j+1}.- ¿Cuál será el valor de término número {x} de la siguiente sucesión:\n')

    for i in range(1, r+1):
        a=d+i*g
        s1,s2,s3=(d+g), (x-1), (((d+g)+(a)+(((d+g)+(a))/2))/3)-(d+g)
        respuesta=(s2*s3)+s1
        print(f'    {a}', end="")
        archivo.write(f'    {a}')
        if i in (r, r-1):
            alm.append(f'{respuesta}')

print('\n———————————————————————————————————————————————————\n\n')
archivo.write('\n———————————————————————————————————————————————————\n\n')

up=0
for i in range(0, len(alm), 2):
    up+=1
    print(f'{up}.-{ alm[i]}', end=" ")
    archivo.write(f'{up}.-{ alm[i]}\n')
archivo.close()
```